# AngularJS - Can you reference a repeater variable in a block of javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simply put, I'm using AngularJS trying to do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <a id="mybutton" href="link{{thing.Id}}">Click</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#mybutton").click(function()
      {
        alert("Id: " + {{thing.Id}});
      });
    </script>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Both that, and alert("Id: " + thing.Id); yield errors (unespected token '{' and 'thing' is not defined, respectively). Is there a way that I can access thing.Id from a block of javascript within the repeater's scope?

To add a practical reason, I'd like to build and redirect to a URL using that value and a few other things in javascript (where I have access to jquery).

Comment: Note the documentation suggests using ng-href instead of href: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

Answer (score 6):

Mike, using angular expressions ({{thing.id}}) in the  tag won't work since angular.js is not a text-based template system but rather uses DOM as its templates. Here is more on this topic: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Now, coming back to your question: what you are trying to do can be done very easily in angular.js without using jQuery, here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/n6UfC/

The trick is to use a ng-click on your href:

```
<a ng-click="click(thing.id)">Click</a>
```

and then a click-handler function in your controller:

```
$scope.click = function(thingId) {
    alert("Id: " + thingId);
    //$location.path('/some/path/'+thingId);
}
```

In the controller's function you can use jQuery instructions but you would be better off using angular's $location service: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)

Comment: Great answer pkozlowski. To OP: I'm sorry for giving you a solution that wasn't even close to correct. It was really wrong of me to answer a question about a template engine I haven't used.

Answer (score 1):

I would store it to the element like "data-id={{thing.id}}"

Then from javascript read the ID back using the data attribute.